# How to select multiple tags in XPath?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, scrapy, tags

one thing I'm trying to implement in my code is a XPath to extract results of 2 different tags, in such a way that the results shown on the screen present these attributes together.

I've tried with union functions for the 2 different XPaths but the results are presented in different lines:

```
xpath1(for tag1) | xpath2(for tag2)
```

would like to have the results this way: results: `tag1` , `tag2`

Any ideas? Thanks in advance,

Comment: I found your question hard to understand. Try to reformulate it in format of `data` --> `desired output`. More concrete you are - better.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly you want the result of two tags in one for example list, in that case:

```py
response.xpath('//tag1 | //tag2').getall()
```

you can do this as well.

Additionally you can attach any other expressions to both tags.

ِYou may also want to visit [XPath syntax on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp).

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

`//*[self::tag1 or self::tag2][` *predicate* `]`

will select elements named `tag1` or `tag2` that also satisfy an additional *predicate*.

Comma vs line separation of the results is a function of the hosting language/tool, not XPath itself.